# Whay have certain macro's stopped working overnight?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this macro and several others exactly the same just different cell numbers for years. Today I am getting a "Runtime error 13 mismatch" and cannot figure out why. I have not changed anything.

```
Sub PayALL_ByDate1()

Dim oRng    As Range
Dim i       As Long
Dim dblRes  As Double

Set oRng = Range("C2:C69")
For i = 1 To oRng.Cells.Count
    If oRng(i).Font.ColorIndex = 1 Or oRng(i).Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic And CDbl(oRng(i).Offset(0, 1)) <= CDbl(Range("D96")) Then
        If InStr(oRng(i).Offset(0, 3), ChrW(8730)) = 0 And CDbl(oRng(i).Offset(0, 1)) <= CDbl(Range("D96")) Then
            dblRes = dblRes + oRng(i)
        End If
    End If
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("D89") = dblRes
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I have tried cut and paste from a past workbook hoping that would work but it did not. Don't know what to do since it has been working for years without change.

Comment: Do any of the relevant Cells now have error values in them?

Comment: Chris, Thank you for responding and I apologize for the late response. There were and are no errors in the cells and nothing had been changed. I am suspecting that the update in Office may have had something to do with this. Like I said, on the same spreadsheet it worked one day and not the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your tests over more lines, and do a bit of checking on the cell values before making any (Eg) numeric comparisons

```vb
Sub PayALL_ByDate1()

    Dim i As Long, c As Range, ws As Worksheet, D96, ci, v
    Dim dblRes  As Double

    Set ws = activesheet
    D96 = CDbl(ws.range("D96").value)

    For Each c in ws.Range("C2:C69").Cells
        ci = c.font.colorindex
        If ci = 1 Or ci = xlColorIndexAutomatic Then
            v = c.offset(0, 1).value
            If isnumeric(v) Then
                If v <= D96 Then
                    If InStr(c.Offset(0, 3), ChrW(8730)) = 0 Then
                        dblRes = dblRes + c.Value
                    End If   'Instr
                End if       '<=D96
            End If           'numeric
        End If               'colorindex
    Next c
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ws.Range("D89") = dblRes
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice example of commenting the finish of each End If.

Comment: Tim, Thank you for responding, and sorry I am late getting back to you. I am going to try your suggestion. I will get back as soon as I can.

Comment: Tim, I have finally tried your macro, and it does work. Yay! I guess I will never know what happened to make mine not work anymore. Thank you so much for your time and expertise. Again I apologize for the late responses. :)